# How do I make triggers fire without error when connecting to an OpenEdge 12.2 database using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, openedge, progress-db, datadirect

I am connecting to an OpenEdge 12.2.0 database using the latest OpenEdge JDBC driver. The OpenEdge database is using Eclipse Temurin JDK version 11.0.14.101 and the application that connects via JDBC is using Eclipse Temurin JDK version 8.0.322.6. Both the database and the application are running on the same Windows 10 PC.

I can create triggers without issue, but when I cause a trigger to fire by updating a row via JDBC, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Failed during dynamic load of Java dynamic library. Reason = [126]The specified module could not be found.
[jvm].
```

I did some research and found the following articles that address this issue:

https://community.progress.com/s/article/P66180

https://community.progress.com/s/article/21181

I called the `sql_env` script before starting the OpenEdge database and set my `CLASSPATH` and `PATH` environment variables as advised in the above articles, but my application continues to throw this exception when it causes a trigger to fire. I first tried setting my environment variables using `%DLC%` and then tried using the absolute path. I suspect that the above articles are outdated, as they do not include 12.x in the affected versions and the second article only has instructions for Windows NT / 2000.

Does anyone know what I need to do to prevent this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the root cause of the issue was, but it stopped throwing the exception after I reinstalled OpenEdge.